# Python 3 on Android using TerminalIDE

Tags: android, python-3.x, terminal-ide

I want to code Python 3 on my Android device. So I went through [Lanky Cyril's blog](http://blog.lankycyril.com/post/39473303019) post on using the Terminal IDE to put all that I needed to do code on an Android terminal. For Python 2.X that is installed on the blog, it works like a charm.

So I installed Python 3 using the same instructions. This is what I get when I try to start Python 3:

```
terminal++:~$ ~/python3                                                                                                                                              
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
Segmentation fault
```

I made sure:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.python3forandroid/files/python3
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONHOME}/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload
```

I also checked on why [python 3 is not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec)  on StackOverflow.

So the problem could be the python build. Has anyone worked around this?

Comment: Once you go past Android 5+, you will need to install ```termux``` app and install ```vim``` using ```apt-get vim``` command. Termux has Python 3 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out the solution by going to the Python-for-Android (Py4A) home and found the script that allows Python3 to run as a "Stand alone" on Android.

There are 3 ways to do this:

- I created the "standalone.sh" script, saved it at "HOME"(`export HOME=/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files`),
  changed its mode to executable, called it and python appeared.
- I opened the ~/.bashrc and pasted copied in the code:

> ```
> export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard/com.googlecode.python3forandroid
> export PY34A=/data/data/com.googlecode.python3forandroid/files/python3
> export PY4A_EXTRAS=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras
> PYTHONPATH=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras/python3
> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$PY34A/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload
> export PYTHONPATH
> export TEMP=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras/python3/tmp
> export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP
> export PYTHONHOME=$PY34A
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PY34A/lib
> $PYTHONHOME/bin/python3 "$@"
> ```

Note that this means every time you launch Terminal IDE, you will automatically load Python and find yourself at the Python prompt.

- To launch Python the normal way, like shown by Lanky Cyril, paste the following code in the .bashrc:

> ```
> export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard/com.googlecode.python3forandroid
> export PY34A=/data/data/com.googlecode.python3forandroid/files/python3
> export PY4A_EXTRAS=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras
> PYTHONPATH=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras/python3
> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$PY34A/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload
> export PYTHONPATH
> export TEMP=$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/extras/python3/tmp
> export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP
> export PYTHONHOME=$PY34A
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PY34A/lib
> ```

You will notice that the last line in the second solution has been taken out and put in an executable file "~/python". Here is the code:

```
  #!/system/bin/sh   
  /data/data/com.googlecode.python3forandroid/files/python3/bin/python3 "$@"
```

I used the second one so that when I launch Terminal IDE, I get my Python prompt instantly. I installed the third solution so that, should I leave the Python prompt, I have a way to get back in the same terminal session.