# c++ use python3 , run error

Tags: c++, python-3.x, anaconda

setting : win10 + vs2015 (Debug 32bits) + anaconda3 (32bits)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");
    PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.plot(range(5))");
    PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.show()");
    Py_Exit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

When it runs, program crash.

[image: Crash image]

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings Also, please check this thread: https://bugs.python.org/issue27054

Comment: make sure the environment variables are correctly set, especially `PYTHONHOME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Python thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue27054) you need to install Python 3.x as administrator. Right click on installer > run as administrator

Also, please check your environment variables after installation to ensure that [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) have been set to locations where your installed modules can be found.

Comment: pythonhome and pythonpath are ok. I failed again, anyway, 3Q. I use python2, and i just make it.