# No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python

My operating system is Ubuntu 17.10.

I have am trying to run (and develop) a python project, but when I do I get:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f8c459bf740 (most recent call first):
```

I have tried advice from [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings), namely:

1. I have removed old virtual environment,
2. create a new one, named `venv`
3. run `source venv/bin/activate`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Also, in pycharm, I have gone File > Settings > Project  > Project Interrupter - and set this to use the same virtual environment.

I have also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3`

But I still get the same error.

Comment: May I know the python version you are using? @Magick

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.3

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/640010/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-unable-to-get-the-locale-encoding-syntaxe

Comment: Safest way to call pip is `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I've found this message to be caused, on setting up uwsgi, by an invalid pointer to the virtual environment in the ".ini" file.

Comment: 100% I had the wrong permissions on my virtualenv and this comment led me to evaluate that. It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings" after updating to macOS Catalina.

I was having multiple versions of Python installed in my system.

Removing all the python versions(2.7 and 3.7.4) from macOS system and reinstalling the latest python 3.8 worked for me.

To remove a python from macOS, I've followed the instructions from here [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)