# Dead Jupyter Kernel with python3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I am trying to use jupyter notebook with python3. Then I added the kernel with

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

But when I start a notebook it shows a Dead kernel message, and the terminal shows

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

If I choose python2 kernel it works well. I can run python command in console without any issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: But if I type `python2` or `python3` in terminal it doesn't show any error, it is just for `jupyter notebook` with `python3`, and I am not using a virtual environment.

Comment: Try looking at some of the other solutions? If you're on windows, there's some for that, and also one for Ubuntu. One of those might work!

Answer (score 1):

Try

> `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` 
>   `python3 -m pip install jupyter` 
>   `jupyter notebook` 
>   It worked for me.