# 'encodings' module not found while using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, module, pyinstaller

[image]

Using python 3.6, all additional libraries required by program are available (and were included in process), but this error is occurring even when there is already hook module available in pyinstaller dir.

Comment: We have no information to start thinking an answer. How did you use pyinsteller? How do you use `encoding`?

Comment: used this code: pyinstaller filename.py, process compiles perfectly,but when i run the executable, this error shows up

Comment: Still not enough information. I use it without problems. Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings . Does it work directly (without pyinstaller)?