# Error while creating virtual enviroment in PyCharm

Tags: python, encoding, pycharm, python-venv

I was using PyCharm for a 2-3 months already. But suddenly, two days ago, it stopped working properly. The thing is, whenever I try to create virtual environment, it shows:
[Pycharm Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LU7Y.png)

I have installed Python 3.7.1, and also included PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables to system (I am using Windows 10) as it was shown here:
[ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

I've already reinstalled PyCharm, and also tried other versions of Python, but no use (I always put check to "add Python to PATH" when installing)

I've checked all forums and other sites, but haven't found solution yet.
Thanks beforehand

[Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjewG.png)

Comment: Please file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have the variables in both user and system. Just stick to one or the other depending if you want it system wide or just your local user.
Possibly the Python home has a trailing '\' which might cause an issue in your user variable.

Comment: No use( Before system, I created variables only in user part, but nothing good happened