# Deploying django On Amazon Ec2 python error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a django web app under one instance. After configuring the httpd.conf file, and copying what is needed in the /var/www/html, I run the apache service but I get this error when I try to access through the url:

```
Current thread 0x00007fbe92454840 (most recent call first):
[Sat Dec 29 15:03:19.205869 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5137] AH00052: child pid 6377 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Sat Dec 29 15:03:19.206506 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5137] AH00052: child pid 6378 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fbe92454840 (most recent call first):
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fbe92454840 (most recent call first):
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: Not sure if it's a windows machine, but anyway there is a known issue https://bugs.python.org/issue27054 with python 3 installation on windows if it was not run as administrator.

Please provide more information about your environment