# Problem when strat python via terminal in manjaro linux (arch)

Tags: python, python-3.x, archlinux, manjaro

i have try to start my python via terminal console, but i dont know why there is a problem when i started this.

when i started python get like this
[image: python [![pythoneror]

please help me, i dont knwo wha to do, iam new in arch. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: I don't know why this happens, which is why I'm not leaving an answer... but a colleague told me to do `unset PYTHONHOME` before calling python. This fixes the error for me.