# Django is crashing and log is showing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'" after Ubuntu Upgrades

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

So I made a huge mistake..
We had a running Django app on an Ubuntu server on AWS
I was in the process of updating the website, and after I pulled my latest ORIGIN, everything was ok, and the changes were applied.

Ubuntu asked me to update/upgrade 150+ packages + 2 important security ones.. I am mostly a front-end developer and this was very new to me, so I thought what's the worst that can happen?

I used the command do-release-upgrade as Ubuntu suggested, and I wish it did not..

After everything was done updating, the website crashed, and the error log is being filled up by this error:

```
[Fri Jun 07 07:36:52.723940 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 9174:tid 139960510220032] [client 202.142.63.118:42070] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal-repo/foodlegal/uploads/documents/1704.pdf$
[Fri Jun 07 17:37:27.338040 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9171:tid 139960774047488] ERROR django.security.DisallowedHost 2019-06-07 17:37:24,205 exception 9171 139960774047488 /home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djang$

//this is when the website was working last, below is when it stopped


[Fri Jun 07 07:39:24.035879 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9168:tid 139960902834048] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 572, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
[Fri Jun 07 07:39:55.591467 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1243:tid 139820063610752] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Fri Jun 07 07:39:55.593400 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 1243:tid 139820063610752] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Fri Jun 07 07:39:55.594420 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1243:tid 139820063610752] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 07 07:39:55.594443 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1243:tid 139820063610752] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502102 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192] ERROR django.request 2019-06-07 17:40:18,499 exception 1247 139819934824192 /home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/$
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502158 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502161 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]   File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502165 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]     response = get_response(request)
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502167 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]   File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502170 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]     response = self._get_response(request)
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502173 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]   File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502176 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502178 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]   File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502181 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502184 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]   File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal-repo/inhouse/views.py", line 2052, in get_document_file_two
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502186 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]     fo = open(file_path, "rb")
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502190 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal-repo/foodlegal/uploads/documents/181.pdf'
[Fri Jun 07 17:40:18.502196 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 1247:tid 139819934824192]
[Fri Jun 07 07:43:20.381484 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 1250:tid 139819699070720] [client 202.142.63.118:42268] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal-repo/foodlegal/uploads/documents/1704.pdf$
[Fri Jun 07 07:44:59.388064 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1243:tid 139820063610752] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 572, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
[Fri Jun 07 07:48:56.811621 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 12808:tid 140344454007744] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 07 07:48:56.811709 2019] [core:notice] [pid 12808:tid 140344454007744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

[Fri Jun 07 07:48:56.811709 2019] [core:notice] [pid 12808:tid 140344454007744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
//and it keeps repeating
```

I have been researching for literally 7 hours, and I have tried many solutions that other people suggested like creating a new virtual environment.

It's been suggested to try and reset PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH, but I have been trying, I am not experienced with Python nor Django at all.

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Release:        18.04

Codename:       bionic

Python Current version: 3.5.2

Stupid me did not take a snapshot of the server as I thought I wouldn't need it...

I could use all the help I can get. What can you suggest for me?

Comment: no module found is a common python error. there are many possibilities. In you case, some of old package is no longer compatible. update, upgrade sudo pip3 install . there are a lot of solution online.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to start? I am really desperate here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st turn off all update to prevent further mistake.

then. remove and reinstall python 3. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/ follow this link to get python 3 up. High chance a lot of python 3 modules is not running.

After that follow this [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

```
m -rf venv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At last, reinstall django, follow this  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-18-04 to get django up

**set up PYTHONPATH accordingly**. this is very important use google if necessary

If some other package is not running, go find its GitHub root and use the script provide in github readme to install it.

Re run all your things again.