# Run .py script in Qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5

i want to run (after i click a button) a .py Script

I already tried the following Code

```
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;

    params << "createJSON.py";
    p.start("python.exe", params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
```

My Python Script create a JSON-File when it runs successfully.
So i can see if the runs successfully.

Comment: Do you actually get to the point where `stdout` is read?

Comment: i get a empty string.

Comment: Have you tried reading `stderr`? Also, according to the documentation, *If the process starts successfully, QProcess will emit started(); otherwise, errorOccurred() will be emitted.* Have you tried hooking these signals to a lambda handler to see what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to write a more detailed version of your code.

```cpp
    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;

    params << "createJSON.py";
    QObject::connect(&p, &QProcess::started, []() {
        qInfo() << "Process started!";
    });
    QObject::connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [&p]() {
        qWarning() << "Error occurred" << p.errorString();
    });

    p.start("python.exe", params);
    p.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();

    qDebug() << "OUT" << p_stdout;
    qDebug() << "ERR" << p_stderr;
```

This effectively leads to an error. In my case, I get the following:

> Process started!
>
> OUT ""
>
> ERR "python.exe: can't open file 'createJSON.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n"

It may be different in your case. Either way, using the `errorOccurred` signal along with the `errorString` method will allow you to debug cases where the process actually cannot start. Reading `stderr` will allow you to debug cases where the process starts, but does not run as expected.

Comment: Thank you.  Now i get: 1. "Process starded!" 2. "Error occured: Process crashed"   3. "OUT "" "  3. ERR "Fatal Python error: initsfseconding: unable to load the file System codec\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'\n Current thread 0x0000005834 (most recent call first): \n

Comment: I dont have anything like "enconding" …

Comment: Two things. First of all, try invoking the full Python path (if you have several Python versions, that could be the reason): `p.start("C:/Python36/python.exe")` instead of just `"python.exe"`. You may find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings) too (even though the original topic isn't related, many people are posting answers for the issue you're facing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i reinstalled python with the configuration ("Add Python to PATH") and i also make what you say: p.start("C:/…/Python37-32/python.exe, params) but i get the same error.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: yes, same Problem … i reinstalled python now the 3x time and reboot the Computer again

Comment: Have you tried using [setProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment) with [systemEnvironment()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html#systemEnvironment)?

Comment: Yes: QProcessEnviroment env = QProcessEnviroment::systemEnviroment() then: p.setProcessEnviroment(env)