# How to troubleshoot "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>" in Python & buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Through buildozer in Ubuntu, I was running an app I am developing.
However, I faced the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I searched and searched and searched for an adequate method for treating this particular problem on Google. Then, I found few methods to fix  this problem.

For the first attempt, I set: export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.7 as suggested in the error comments. Unfortunately, the same error appeared even with this change. For the second attempt, I tried to delete virtual environment file and reset it as suggested on the following website: [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings). But, again, I failed to eliminate this error.

I saw that some of the posts on Stackoverflow regarding this issue provide repetitive methods. I am stuck with this issue. I would deeply appreciate it if anyone can be kind enough to shed some light on this. 
Blessings.

Comment: What command are you entering when you get the message? That will help narrow down the possible fixes

Comment: @ Daniel Butler
I used: buildozer android deploy debug

Comment: what do `which python` and `python -c 'import encodings'` return?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to avoid this

1. Activate `virtualenv` by `source venv/bin/activate`
2. Set `ENV["PYTHON"]` to correct Python path under the virtualenv
3. Install `PyCall` by `pip install pycall`
4. Open `v0.6/PyCall/deps/deps.jl` with a text editor and replace `const PYTHONHOME = "..."` with `const PYTHONHOME = ""`
5. Run using `PyCall`

[Further details](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/410#issuecomment-406794511)