# 403 Forbidden error for Django app on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache2, http-status-code-403

I've followed [this deploy tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds) of Django for Apache, and did everything as in there. When I try to enter the page with server's ip, I get

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at <my-ip> Port 80
```

Running the app with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` works fine and I can access the app.

Via the apache2 logs I got:

```
Current thread 0x00007fc84606fbc0 (most recent call first):
[Wed Aug 14 01:11:51.141895 2019] [core:notice] [pid 31839:tid 140498145049536] AH00051: child pid 32108 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
$preter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

My config file:

```
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/static
        <Directory /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/datagather/uploaded_files
        <Directory /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/datagather/uploaded_files>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/[my-project-name]/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ernest/[my-project-name]/[my-project-name]/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess my_app python-path=/home/ernest/[my-project-name] python-home=/home/[my-project-name]/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup my_app

</VirtualHost>
```

I've done following changes to [my-project-name]/settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['[my-server-ip]', 'localhost']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'datagather/uploaded_files/')
MEDIA_URL = '/datagather/uploaded_files/'
```

I have also set up proper permissions using

```
sudo chown :www-data [my-project-name]/db.sqlite3
sudo chmod 664 [my-project-name]/db.sqlite3
sudo chown :www-data [my-project-name]/
sudo chown -R :www-data [my-project-name]/datagather/uploaded_files/
sudo chmod -R 775 [my-project-name]/datagather/uploaded_files
```

And it looks like this:

```
ls -la
total 1384
drwxrwxr-x 10    666 www-data    4096 Aug 14 01:05 .
drwx------  5 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 14 00:40 ..
drwxrwxr-x  6 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:25 [dir-in-project]
drwxrwxr-x  6 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:25 [dir-in-project]
drwxrwxr-x  7 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:56 datagather
-rw-rw-r--  1 ernest www-data  212992 Aug 13 23:17 db.sqlite3
-rw-rw-r--  1 ernest ernest         0 Aug 13 23:17 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 ernest ernest       642 Aug 13 23:17 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x  3 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 14 01:30 [my-project-name]
-rw-rw-r--  1 ernest ernest       183 Aug 13 23:17 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 ernest ernest   1152635 Aug 13 23:34 simple_logs.log
drwxrwxr-x  8 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:25 static
drwxrwxr-x  7 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:25 [dir-in-project]
drwxrwxr-x  8 ernest ernest      4096 Aug 13 23:25 [dir-in-project]
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root        4096 Aug 14 01:08 venv
```

Current port usage looks like this (enabled http-traffic and port 80 before)

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

systemd-r   846 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  15597      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd        976            root    3u  IPv4  18092      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        976            root    4u  IPv6  18103      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
apache2    3265            root    4u  IPv6 870246      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    3280        www-data    4u  IPv6 870246      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    3281        www-data    4u  IPv6 870246      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Libraries used in the app (made with pip freeze):

```
Django==2.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
jdcal==1.4.1
numpy==1.16.4
openpyxl==2.6.2
pandas==0.24.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Unidecode==1.1.1
xlrd==1.2.0
```

The app was developed on Python 3.7.1, however on 3.6.8 it seems to work just fine, based on the development server.

I have no idea what am I doing wrong at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try have a go at the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, I've managed to solve the problem.
After some hair pulled, I've thought that the problem lies in fact, that WSGI wants an app in different version of python, which it turned out was incompatible, causing the error by not loading it.

The way I overcame it: I installed python 3.7 as default on my clean Ubuntu server (via PPA deadsnakes; [instruction](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/)), and began the process from scratch. Now everything works.