# How to fix "No module named 'encodings'" in Python3.7.1?

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi

I tried to start uwsgi for myproject(mywords_dict):

```
uwsgi --http :8000  -H /root/mywords_dict/env --chdir mywords_dict -w mywords_dict.wsgi
```

But received the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I am so confused that uwsgi can work well if I run it after entering virtual env .Python version of 'mywords_dict' is 3.7.1. I have checked that the there is encoding package in mywords_dic/env. And I can run python  successfully from there. Does anyone can help?

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Fri Aug 30 00:15:16 2019] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) on 29 August 
2019 13:49:55
os: Linux-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018
nodename: VM_0_17_centos
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root
detected binary path: /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
chdir() to mywords_dict
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3882
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 100001
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 22645)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:42301 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.7.1 (default, Nov 11 2018, 01:35:46)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
Set PythonHome to /root/mywords_dict/env
**Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'**
```

Comment: `Set PythonHome to /root/mywords_dict/env` — do you actually have a working installation of Python 3 in that directory? Can you run `python` from there and `import encodings`?

Comment: You might need to reinstall python or reset virtual env [This might be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: @9000 yes, I can run python from there and import encoding successfully . That is why I am so confused.

Comment: @ryanyang , thank u for sharing. But I can run python and import encodings successfully in virtual env without using uwsgi. It's so wired.

Comment: I occasionally experience this. To fix it I have to do `unset PYTHONHOME` before I call python. In fact, I added it to my `.bashrc` file and the problem went away.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid thanks, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi guys, I finally solved this problem by 'rm -rf env'  and rebuild it . And I still don't know why it happend.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to wrong python virtual environment path. It is defined in you `.ini` file under `home` variable.

What you need to do is assign to this variable path pointing to the **root** of your venv. So if your venv path is `/home/user/project/venv`, just assign this path to the `home` variable. Be sure **not** to include the trailing `/` (slash) in the venv path (since it is later concatenated to `/bin/python` and you'll end up with double slash.

Then save your `.ini` file and try starting uWSGI again.

Comment: I made this exact mistake: I changed the env path in the conf from `/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/envname/bin/` to `/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/envname` and it worked.

Answer (score -4):

I got the same error.
Fixed after trying these steps :

1. Uninstall python(38) as administrator. Checking all the boxes during custom installation, including install for all user and precompiling standard library.
2. Downgrading python38 to 37

I still dont know what & where the error came from though haha.