# What is the cause of this error in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

What is the cause of this error in pycharm on ubuntu?

```
 Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2b344c7740 (most recent call first):
```

Comment: Have you set correct interpreter in pycharm?

Comment: yes.The interpreter has no problem

Comment: Consider checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings). This is due to environment variable not being set properly. Did you, by any chance, update python version after installing Pycharm?

Comment: yes.python updated