# Why can't I run this Python file?

Tags: python, windows

I very recently installed Python 3 on my PC and I'm trying to run this file, but I'm getting an error message:

```
C:\Users\Anoof\Desktop\Python docs>python myexample.py
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000570 (most recent call first):
```

I'm on Windows 10, using Python 3.7. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: your python installation seems broken :( you are up for a long day

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Comment: Read the second answer.

Comment: Could you post the content of `myexample.py`?