# Python no module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, cmd, kivy

I'm trying to install Kivy in cmd. Using Python 3.8.5 and windows 10

When I get to: `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*`

I get an error of: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

`Current thread 0x000012d4 (most recent call first): <no Python frame>`

Not sure what to do, any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running in a virtual env?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings) may help