# Issue with installing packages for Python

Tags: python, cmd, pip, package, conda

I'm having an issue with installing Python packages, I've never had this problem before:
error code:

```
C:\Users\joe_h\.conda>pip install pandas-datareader
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'c:\users\joe_h\anaconda3\anaconda3\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'c:\\users\\joe_h\\anaconda3\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'c:\\users\\joe_h\\anaconda3\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'c:\\users\\joe_h\\anaconda3\\anaconda3\\python38.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'c:\\users\\joe_h\\anaconda3\\anaconda3',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000028f4 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

anyone got any idea what I need to do to start installing packages again? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey there. Maybe [this](https://discuss.python.org/t/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-filesystem-encoding/3173) link might help

Comment: Hey yh i've looked at this many times, PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH have not been changed at all so it's definitely not the same issue. In that string of comments there is someone with the same issue as me, but all the comments below say they're getting the same error and no one has been able to fix it! What is going on this is so weird.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings) issue. your error is because of an Improper Python Installation. You might want to reinstall Python following the steps in the Issue.

Comment: @AryanGarg ah ty, i will try this now

Comment: @KJ hey I don't fully understand what your saying but thank you too. Yh it was after a few new installations when I started getting this problem so makes sense its related to the update.

Comment: @AryanGarg that link has helped, I've reinstall Python and made sure it auto connects to the virtual environments and it's all working now, thank u