# How can I import a Python library into a source code written in Nim?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda3, nim-lang

I would like to import the `numpy` Python library into Nim's code. The following code is my attempt to do so:

```
import os
import nimpy


let pythonPath = "C:/User/Master/anaconda3"
putEnv("PYTHONPATH", pythonPath)
let pythonHome = "C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages"
putEnv("PYTHONHOME", pythonHome)



let np = pyImport("numpy")
let arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
echo "Import numpy is success!"

echo arr
```

This code errors into the following error.

```
C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project>C:/Users/Master/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project>conda activate base

(base) C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project>C:/Users/Master/anaconda3/python.exe c:/MyPrograms/Nim_Programs/Training_Project/CompairPythonAndNim/searchPythonFile.py
C:\Users\Master\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py

(base) C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project>nim c -r ImportPython.nim
Hint: used config file 'C:\Users\Master\.choosenim\toolchains\nim-1.6.12\config\nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: used config file 'C:\Users\Master\.choosenim\toolchains\nim-1.6.12\config\config.nims' [Conf]
.........................................................................................................
CC: ../../../Users/Master/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.6.12/lib/system.nim
CC: ImportPython.nim
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: gc: refc; opt: none (DEBUG BUILD, `-d:release` generates faster code)
59660 lines; 2.194s; 93.867MiB peakmem; proj: C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project\ImportPython.nim; out: C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project\ImportPython.exe [SuccessX]
Hint: C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project\ImportPython.exe  [Exec]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages'
  PYTHONPATH = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3'
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\MyPrograms\\Nim_Programs\\Training_Project\\ImportPython.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\MyPrograms\\Nim_Programs\\Training_Project\\ImportPython.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages'
  sys.path = [
    'C:/User/Master/anaconda3',
    'C:\\Users\\Master\\anaconda3\\python310.zip',
    'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages\\DLLs',
    'C:/User/Master/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages\\lib',
    'C:\\MyPrograms\\Nim_Programs\\Training_Project',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000b54 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
Error: execution of an external program failed: 'C:\MyPrograms\Nim_Programs\Training_Project\ImportPython.exe '
```

I have installed Nim and anaconda3. In my environment, I can use `pip`, `conda`, `nim`, `nimble` commands in shell. In addition to these, I have already imported nimpy.
What should I do to import `numpy` into Nim's code?

Comment: as per the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`.. try installing it through a package manager

Comment: I have already tried "pip install encodings" and "conda install encodings", but command prompt displays PackageNotFoundError.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings)