# Python3 won't run - no module name encodings

Tags: python, installation

When I try to run a python command I get a warning about missing module 'encodings'.  So I set the PYTHONHOME variable as described in other SO answers, but it still can't find 'encodings'

```
[root@fedora ~]# python help
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python/lib64/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python/lib64/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f241f6dd740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[root@fedora ~]#
```

In case it matters, I recently installed a cross-compilation environment (for Raspberry Pi) on this x86_64 Fedora 34 host. But I don't think that should matter. I tried to reinstall python with `dnf reinstall python` but now Python doesn't run, neither do dnf and other utilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132755/6340496 ?

Comment: Saw that already, but can't run pip because python does not run.

Comment: Starting to think may have to wipe disk, unless someone can offer a simple workaround

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was a Permissions problem or issues ensure that the user executing the command has read access to the entire virtual environment directory.
/usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python ( Here am relating to your error log path) You can adjust permissions using chmod and chown commands.

For example, you might want to make sure the running user say “data_user”  user can traverse the "python3.9" directory ( This is your folder Just before your Virtual Environment folder)   can and read the virtual environment:

```
sudo chown -R root:data_user /usr/lib64/python3.9/venv/bin/python sudo
chmod -R 755 /usr/lib64/python3.9
```

Other suggestion I can suggest is to disabled AppArmor or any firewall you using and SELinux temporarily

Those who are experiencing the same with Apache replace with the Apache user ( www-data) instead of "data_user" or the user for your given web server