Forbidden access to deployed Django website
I have deployed my django website, following Corey Schafer tutorial (Python Django Tutorial: Deploying Your Application (Option #1) - Deploy to a Linux Server). But I have an error and I'm not sure why.

I runned this:
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

error
Current thread 0x00007f603fccb780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Thu Aug 15 13:12:35.962154 2024] [wsgi:warn] [pid 72344:tid 140051363968896] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=72344): Unable to stat Python home /home/m_user/django_site/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/m_user/django_site/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/m_user/django_site/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/m_user/django_site/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/m_user/django_site/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/m_user/django_site/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/m_user/django_site/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/m_user/django_site/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/m_user/django_site/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

I get this when I run this ls -la
total 40
drwxr-x---  6 m_user m_user 4096 Aug 14 23:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root           root           4096 Aug 14 21:04 ..
-rw-------  1 m_user m_user 1246 Aug 15 01:23 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 m_user m_user  220 Aug 14 21:04 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 m_user m_user 3771 Aug 14 21:04 .bashrc
drwx------  3 m_user m_user 4096 Aug 14 21:36 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 m_user m_user    0 Aug 14 21:04 .cloud-locale-test.skip
drwxrwxr-x 11 m_user www-data       4096 Aug 14 21:42 django_site
drwxrwxr-x  3 m_user m_user 4096 Aug 14 23:07 .local
-rw-r--r--  1 m_user m_user  807 Aug 14 21:04 .profile
drwx------  2 m_user m_user 4096 Aug 14 21:13 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 m_user m_user    0 Aug 14 21:15 .sudo_as_admin_successful

by using sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/django_site.conf, I tried to add LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/m_user/django_site/venv/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-pyXY.so" recommended by forums. But it hasn't work... full code bellow.
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        Alias /static /home/m_user/django_site/static
        <Directory /home/m_user/django_site/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/m_user/django_site/media
        <Directory /home/m_user/django_site/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/m_user/django_site/core>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/m_user/django_site/core/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/m_user/django_site python-home=/home/m_user/django_site/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

        LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/m_user/django_site/venv/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-pyXY.so"

</VirtualHost>

Any other ideas what I could try??? Thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

I removed venv and added a new one, but still doesn't work :(
