# What is the easiest way to remove all packages installed by pip?

Tags: python, pip

I want to revert my Python install back to its base state so I can start using `virtualenv`. Is there an easy way to uninstall only those packages that have been installed after Python was set up?

Comment: Why not just uninstall everything including python? Also maybe add in what OS you are using.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, don't uninstall Python. There's a lot of things that depend on it.

Comment: @Dan uninstalling Python won't remove pip or the packages it installed.

Comment: this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip/67379806#67379806

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The following command should do the trick:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

Alternatively you can skip the creation of any intermediate files (i.e. `requirements.txt`):

```
pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
```

Comment: just to add to this as an extension, `pip3 uninstall -y -r <(pip3 freeze)`

Comment: This works too well! Don't run it in your base conda environment, for example, because it will remove some things required for conda itself to work.

Answer (score 13):

do following

1. store all the pip packages in requirements.txt

   ```
   python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
2. remove all pip packages which menetioned in requirements.txt

   ```
   python -m pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
   ```

Comment: When I did this, it thrown me a fatal python error `Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding`, which states that PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH is not set

Comment: @Naras-KS this may [help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767191/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec-importe)

Comment: Thanks for the information. The error persists even after specifying the respective path to the environment variables, which I did manually. So, I have uninstalled it and reinstalled the python @sahasrara62

Comment: i sugges you to create a new question stating your problem, so other can help you better