# Uninstall all Python packages in Ubuntu 18.04 having multiple python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

When I type `python` and hit tab the following packages are shown

```
python             python3            python3.6m         python3m
python2            python3.6          python3.6m-config  python3m-config
python2.7          python3.6-config   python3-config
```

And when I type `pip list` the following packages are shown

```
absl-py               0.8.0               
apturl                0.5.2               
asn1crypto            0.24.0              
astor                 0.8.0               
astroid               2.2.5               
attrs                 19.1.0              
backcall              0.1.0               
bleach                3.1.0               
Brlapi                0.6.6               
certifi               2018.1.18           
chardet               3.0.4               
command-not-found     0.3                 
cryptography          2.1.4               
cupshelpers           1.0                 
cycler                0.10.0              
decorator             4.4.0               
defer                 1.0.6               
defusedxml            0.6.0               
distro-info           0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 
entrypoints           0.3                 
gast                  0.2.2               
google-pasta          0.1.7               
grpcio                1.23.0              
h5py                  2.9.0               
httplib2              0.9.2               
idna                  2.6                 
ipykernel             5.1.2               
ipython               7.8.0               
ipython-genutils      0.2.0               
ipywidgets            7.5.1               
isort                 4.3.21              
jedi                  0.15.1              
Jinja2                2.10.1              
joblib                0.14.0              
jsonschema            3.0.2               
jupyter               1.0.0               
jupyter-client        5.3.3               
jupyter-console       6.0.0               
jupyter-core          4.5.0               
Keras-Applications    1.0.8               
Keras-Preprocessing   1.1.0               
keyring               10.6.0              
keyrings.alt          3.0                 
kiwisolver            1.1.0               
language-selector     0.1                 
launchpadlib          1.10.6              
lazr.restfulclient    0.13.5              
lazr.uri              1.0.3               
lazy-object-proxy     1.4.2               
louis                 3.5.0               
macaroonbakery        1.1.3               
Markdown              3.1.1               
MarkupSafe            1.1.1               
matplotlib            3.1.1               
mccabe                0.6.1               
mistune               0.8.4               
nbconvert             5.6.0               
nbformat              4.4.0               
netifaces             0.10.4              
nltk                  3.4.5               
notebook              6.0.1               
numpy                 1.17.2              
oauth                 1.0.1               
oauthlib              3.1.0               
olefile               0.45.1              
pandas                0.25.1              
pandocfilters         1.4.2               
parso                 0.5.1               
pexpect               4.2.1               
pickleshare           0.7.5               
Pillow                5.1.0               
pip                   19.3.1              
prometheus-client     0.7.1               
prompt-toolkit        2.0.9               
protobuf              3.9.1               
ptyprocess            0.6.0               
pycairo               1.16.2              
pycrypto              2.6.1               
pycups                1.9.73              
Pygments              2.4.2               
pygobject             3.26.1              
pylint                2.3.1               
pymacaroons           0.13.0              
PyNaCl                1.1.2               
pyparsing             2.4.2               
pyRFC3339             1.0                 
pyrsistent            0.15.4              
PySocks               1.7.1               
python-apt            1.6.4               
python-dateutil       2.6.1               
python-debian         0.1.32              
pytz                  2018.3              
pyxdg                 0.25                
PyYAML                3.12                
pyzmq                 18.1.0              
qtconsole             4.5.5               
reportlab             3.4.0               
requests              2.18.4              
requests-oauthlib     1.3.0               
requests-unixsocket   0.1.5               
scikit-learn          0.21.3              
scipy                 1.3.1               
SecretStorage         2.3.1               
Send2Trash            1.5.0               
setuptools            41.2.0              
simplejson            3.13.2              
six                   1.11.0              
sklearn               0.0                 
swampy                3.0.1               
system-service        0.3                 
systemd-python        234                 
tb-nightly            1.14.0a20190603     
tensorflow            2.0.0b1             
termcolor             1.1.0               
terminado             0.8.2               
testpath              0.4.2               
textblob              0.15.3              
tf-estimator-nightly  1.14.0.dev2019060501
tornado               6.0.3               
traitlets             4.3.2               
tweepy                3.8.0               
typed-ast             1.4.0               
ubuntu-drivers-common 0.0.0               
ufw                   0.36                
unattended-upgrades   0.1                 
urllib3               1.22                
virtualenv            16.7.5              
wadllib               1.3.2               
wcwidth               0.1.7               
webencodings          0.5.1               
Werkzeug              0.15.6              
wheel                 0.30.0              
widgetsnbextension    3.5.1               
wrapt                 1.11.2              
xkit                  0.0.0               
zope.interface        4.3.2
```

I want to remove all the packages but **KEEP** those which are **IMPORTANT TO THE OPERATING SYSTEM**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove all packages installed by PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870755/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip)

Comment: No it doesn't provide necessary details and I want to run any command which I don't understand as I am using Ubuntu and can't uninstall python if things go south.

Answer (score 0):

If I create an ubuntu 18.04 container, and install python, python3 and do a pip list these are the packages I get. So in theory, you can remove all but these packages:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash

# inside the docker container:

$ apt update
$ apt install python python-pip  python3 python3-pip
$ pip list
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
cryptography (2.1.4)
enum34 (1.1.6)
idna (2.6)
ipaddress (1.0.17)
keyring (10.6.0)
keyrings.alt (3.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pygobject (3.26.1)
pyxdg (0.25)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.11.0)
wheel (0.30.0)

$ pip3 list
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
cryptography (2.1.4)
idna (2.6)
keyring (10.6.0)
keyrings.alt (3.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pygobject (3.26.1)
pyxdg (0.25)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.11.0)
wheel (0.30.0)
```