# Python can't load File System Codec and can't add it to PATH

Tags: python

When trying to install modules in Python 3.5, I receive an error saying that Python can't load the file system codec and the shell then freezes.

This is the same, or very similar, problem as here:

[Py_Initialize fails - unable to load the file system codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec)

with a few notable exceptions. Most importantly, the solution from that Question won't work for me, because Python 2.7 is the production version on this server and therefore **Python 3.5 can't be safely added to the environment variables**.

The other differences are that the OS is **Windows Server 2008** and that I'm trying to run Python directly in the command prompt shell, not via Visual Studio.

I am able to run Python 3.5 fine from within the Eclipse IDE, however I need to install some whl files (modules) which I believe must take place on the command line.

If I try to run Python on the command line at all, then it crashes with this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "E:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00006a2c (most recent call first):
```

I note that the error message references Python 2.7 even though I'm in the `Python35` directory and am trying to use Python 3.5

Typing `pip3` causes the same error message above and causes Python to crash.

Comment: Same problem a year later with Python 3.6