# Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec after anaconda unistall (windows)

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Import Error: no module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001558 (Most recent call first)

python is causing error and crashing after i uninstalled Anaconda, i looked at similar posts of mentioning reset the  venv, however i there are no commands available for windows.

Does anyone know what may have happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Py\_Initialize fails - unable to load the file system codec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec)