# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding error when Python called from Abaqus subroutine

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

I'm attempting to use Python in concert with user subroutines to change material properties of a model between analysis steps. The update script `Update_Properties.py` uses `mpi4py` and is called from the `UEXTERNALDB` subroutine like so:

```
STAT=SYSTEM("mpiexec -n 4 python /scratch/Update_Properties.py")
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/gpfs/gpfs1/apps2/abaqus/2019/SimulationServices/V6R2019x/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is on a RHEL HPC, using Python 3.6.1 and Abaqus 2019. The job is submitted via SLURM. Python 3.6.1 is used in instead of Abaqus Python because the latter lacks `mpi4py`

I've checked to ensure Python 3.6.1 is on the `PATH`, and is the first Python present. I've also checked the `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`, both of which are not set on the system. I've noticed that when Abaqus runs, it adds a bunch of temporary entries to `PYTHONPATH` though.

If `Update_Properties.py` is directly submitted as a job, the script works just fine.

So far I have tried:

1. Specifying the full path to Python 3.6.1 in the `SYSTEM()` call
2. `unset PYTHONPATH` immediately before the call to `Update_Properties.py`
3. `unset PYTHONHOME` immediately before the call to `Update_Properties.py`
4. Setting `PYTHONPATH` to the directories containing the Python 3.6.1 install immediately before the call to `Update_Properties.py`
5. Calling `Update_Properties.py` using a bash script rather than directly

However, every time I get the aforementioned error.

I've looked at other question both on Stack Exchange and elsewhere, in particular:

[External call to Python3.5 doesnot work from within Abaqus python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552279/external-call-to-python3-5-doesnot-work-from-within-abaqus-python)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/640010/fatal-python-error-py-initialize-unable-to-get-the-locale-encoding-syntaxe

The answers given for these types of problems typically revolve around clearing or editing `PYTHONPATH` and/or `PYTHONHOME` which I've tried to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I bypassed this issue by using `pyinstaller` to turn the `Update_Properties.py` script into a stand-alone executable, and calling that instead.