# Python 3 can't run after installing anaconda2

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using MacOS. First, I installed anaconda3 to install python3.6. And then, i need python2.7 to be installed. Then i installed anaconda2. After the installation, I can't run python 3.6. I installed Anaconda2 and 3 in different folder. The error appears

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
>   Current thread 0x00007fffb3c0c3c0 (most recent call first):
>   Abort trap: 6

How to fix it? Thank you so much

Comment: Need more information. Please post outputs of the following command. `which python3`, `which python2`

Comment: Is-MacBook-Pro:~ d$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Is-MacBook-Pro:~ d$ which python2
/Applications/anaconda2/bin/python2
Is-MacBook-Pro:~ d$

Comment: [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694730/1509809)