# cx_Freeze pygame error

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

i've recently started working with pygame and wanted to create an executable using cx_Freeze but i encounter an error every time i try to run my exe file.

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: invalid flags 1530097318 in 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000016f0 (most recent call first):
```

Here's my setup.py file:

```
import cx_Freeze


import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python37-64\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Python37-64\\tcl\\tk8.6"

executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable('snk.py')]


cx_Freeze.setup(
    name='Snake',
    options={'build_exe':{'packages':['pygame'], 'include_files':['beep.wav', 'lost.wav', 'apple.png', 'snakehead2.png', 'apple2.png', 'tail.png', 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\MAGNETOB.TTF']}},
    description='Snake Game',
    executables=executables


    )
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: This error usually comes from mixing up Python 2 and Python 3—e.g., by having a `PYTHONHOME` environment variable pointing at your Python 2 root but then running Python 3. So, the first question is: do you have multiple Python versions on your system? Do you have a `PYTHONHOME` env variable? Or `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: While we're at it, do you have a `PYTHON_HOME` env variable? That _should_ do nothing, but confuses some embedding sample code that's been copied and pasted a million places, which might for all I know include `cz_Freeze`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec). I think it's not really a dup, because, while it's about the same root problem, it's about embedding Python manually in your own app, which for a `cx_Freeze` user is something that happens deep under the covers and you likely don't even know what it's doing. But much of the information is still relevant here.

Comment: @abarnert i only have one version of python running(3.7)

Comment: The next biggest possibility is still a `PYTHONHOME`/`PYTHONPATH` problem: Python isn't finding the _wrong_ `Lib` directory, but just isn't finding one at all (possibly because `cx_Freeze` isn't copying it into your executable), or that the `Lib` directory is missing either the `encodings` subdirectory, or one of the files in it (or, possibly, `codecs.py` or one of the `*codec*` dynamic libs, but it seems more likely to be something like `encodings/utf_16.py` or `encodings/cp1252.py`). Also: what is your system's default character set (aka "OEM code page")? Is it cp1252 or different?

Comment: Anyway, please answer _all_ of the questions I asked, and read the linked question. If you just answer one of the questions and ignore the rest, there's no way to help you unless someone gets really lucky.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847455/executable-made-with-pyinstaller-experiences-fatal-python-error-initfsencoding/51848043#51848043).You are using `python 3.7`. As far as I have tested , modules like `pyinstaller` and `cx_freeze` don't seem to be working in this version. Try uninstalling your python (don't forget to backup your files before), and installing [`python 3.6.3`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/) or any other `python 3` version except `python 3.7`.