# Executable made with pyinstaller experiences "Fatal python error: initfsencoding"

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, pyinstaller

I am able to run my python (python 3.7) program on my pc from sublime text. The program uses tkinter and sqlite3. Does pyinstaller not support them?

The error I'm getting when running it (by simply double-clicking the file created in `dist`:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec 
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'
```

If anyone has some experience with this all help will be greatly appreciated!

I can post the code if the issue might be in the code itself.

Comment: Thats the problem with the `pyinstaller` , not with `tkinter` or other module. I am sure that you are using `python 3.7`. Try uninstalling your python (recover your files before), and install [`python 3.6.3`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/).

Comment: Edited to include python version. Yes, I am running 3.7. Why `python 3.6.3` ?

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer too , you can try using any python 3.6 version except 3.7. Same happened with me when I was coding this [GUI application](https://github.com/BlackSkull01001/cx_freeze_GUI/) which also uses a module similiar to `pyinstaller` i.e. `cx_Freeze`

Comment: Oh my god it worked! Thank you! Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `python 3.7`. As far as I have tested , modules like `pyinstaller` don't seem to be working in this version. Try uninstalling your python (don't forget to backup your files before), and installing [`python 3.6.3`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/) or any other `python 3` version except `python 3.7`. Same happened with me and I did this. It worked.