# How can I compile a GUI python program into .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, compilation, executable

I am using Python 3.7.0 with tkinter to create an executable GUI

I've tried PyInstaller to create the executable GUI it does't throw an error but when I run the program windows shows an error message.

When I click show problem details this is what it shows:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
 Application Name:  Jpeg-Raw_WizardGUI.exe
 Application Version:   0.0.0.0
 Application Timestamp: 5a2e9f94
 Fault Module Name: ucrtbase.DLL
 Fault Module Version:  10.0.10240.16390
 Fault Module Timestamp:    55a5bf73
 Exception Code:    40000015
 Exception Offset:  0007d85a
 OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
 Locale ID: 2057
 Additional Information 1:  c89f
 Additional Information 2:  c89f96664d7d2cd53e94623624561d56
 Additional Information 3:  25d2
 Additional Information 4:  25d26db9b8f08829e05b4d3e158d5678
```

I've tried searching online and have not found a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847455/executable-made-with-pyinstaller-experiences-fatal-python-error-initfsencoding/51848043#51848043).You are using `python 3.7`. As far as I have tested , modules like `pyinstaller` and `cx_Freeze` don't seem to be working in this version. Try uninstalling your python 3.7 (don't forget to backup your files before), and installing [`python 3.6.3`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/) or any other `python 3` version except `python 3.7`.

#### Edit:

In comments, you said that `windows doesn't throw an error anymore but instead of a GUI window opening a console window opens for a second and then closes`. Well, changing the version worked but now it is problem either with your program or with `pyinstaller`. You can use my [`Python Executable File Maker`](https://github.com/BlackSkull01001/cx_freeze_GUI/) and let me know if it works fine or throw any error or shows improper behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, windows doesn't throw an error anymore but instead of a GUI window opening a console window opens for a second and then coloses

Comment: @MJCS Try building the program with my [`Python executable file maker`](https://github.com/BlackSkull01001/cx_freeze_GUI/) and let me know if it don't works properly or throw any error..

Comment: I'll try this when I can next use a windows computer

Comment: @MJCS And which OS are you currently using?

Comment: Debian (raspbian) Linux

Comment: The code works in the IDLE but not in the command line or with the compiled version. Apparently this is because the IDLE uses Tkinter and my program is running off that. Perhaps I have imported Tkinter wrongly, the method I am using in my program is “import tkinter as tk”

Comment: FIXED turns out instead of putting root.mainloop() I put root.mainloop without the brackets. Thanks for the help @Nouman