# Making exe file with the help of pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote my GUI calculator with Python and Tkinter and now I'm trying to make exe file from my .py file. I'm using pyinstaller to do this, but when i compile my file and try to open it i get this error[image]

But my program perfectly work when i run it in Pycharm. So, I just don't know what to do.

My code:https://github.com/Unknown-reader/Python-Calculator/blob/master/ffff.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executable made with pyinstaller experiences "Fatal python error: initfsencoding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847455/executable-made-with-pyinstaller-experiences-fatal-python-error-initfsencoding)

Comment: Please check my answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848043/8321664