# Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was having python 3 and my codes were running very good but I was installing a program which provides downloading python 2 with it from that moment when I run any program it gives me a fatal error that looks like that:

Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00004f08 (most recent call first):

My Os is windows 10, please help, it has something to do with path and variables in the system but I don't know the steps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec