# No modue named encodings

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to learn Python. I am using Pycharm Community Edition. A couple of hours back it was working fine, but  now it is not working and showing an error while running.

I am getting this error message:

> C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Basics\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/Basics/Day1.py Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
> Current thread 0x00002fe0 (most recent call first):

I don't know how to fix it.

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: This looks directly related to the problems described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec)