# VirtualEnv the System cannot find the path specified : '...Python3.6\\DLL'

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am trying to downgrade python for tensorflow in a virtual env, the only way I found how to do this was to download Python3.6 and use the command

```
virtualenv -m TempEnv C:\Dev\Projects -p C:\Dev\Projects\Python3.6\python.exe
```

but I am getting the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Dev\\Projects\\Python3.6\\DLLs'
```

Why is it looking for a DLL folder? this was not in the python 3.6 embedded download

Is there a better way to do this through virtual environments? I dont want to screw up my global python installation and libraries by downgrading everything

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

In my case using Windows and Python 3.10 embedded, I've just added the missing folder DLLs (letting it empty) in the respective Python directory and it works.

In your case you would have to build the new empty folder `C:\Dev\Projects\Python3.6\DLLs` and it should work

Comment: I tried it, but hit this:

"Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec"

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694706/316578

Answer (score 0):

Had to download the windows installer, doesn't work with embedded version

Then the command line is simply `virtualenv C:\Dev\Projects\venv -p C:\Dev\Projects\Python3.6\python.exe`