# How to override x64 Python interpreter call when embedding Python in x86 C++ application

Tags: python, c++, x86, 64-bit, embedding

I have 2 versions of Python installed: x86 and x64 (3.10.).
Only x64 is allowed in `PATH` due to internal technicalities.

The task is to embed Python (x86) in C++ x86 app.
Again, due to internal specifics, only this type of embedding can happen at the moment.

Question: How can I re-direct `Py_Initialize()`; to point to specifically x86 `PYTHONHOME`.

What I have tried so far was to:

1. Define const wchar_t* that points to place where Python x86 is installed
2. Call `Py_SetPythonHome(...)`;
3. Compiles without errors (in x86 Debug Mode)
4. Execution fails
   (setting explicitly `PYTHONHOME` in env var did not help either)

OS: Windows 10 // Windows Server. IDE: VS-2015/2019

If I do an x64 compilation and/or modify `PATH` to have x86 Python priority -> all is good.

Could someone help and point to where I'm missing something.

Comment: The 32/64-bitness of the embedded interpreter must match that of the C++ program that will be enclosing it because they will be sharing the same C/C++ runtime library (on Windows).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it does match, doesn't it? I have an x86 C++ compilation & try to point to Python x86 dir.
It's only in PATH that there's only x64 PYTHON reference.
I'm not sure how to control the Py_Initialize() sequence. Thanks!

Comment: You said "Only x64 is allowed in `PATH`", so how are you doing this pointing to the Python x86 dir? When you compile a Python C extension, the bit-ness of the runtime it requires goes into the compiled .obj file created, so I am not sure if what's in the `PATH` environment variable when it executes really matters.

Comment: This is essentially the question - how to properly point to the x86 dir of PYTHON if in the PATH the values are pointing to x64.
Currently, I'm doing it like this:

const wchar_t* wcs = _env_path.c_str();
Py_SetPythonHome(wcs);

where _env_path. points to the directory of x86 version.

in C++ the mode is Debug x86.

Still the app crashes without any evidence as to why.

I also found this thread, but could not exactly figure out at the moment what is the correct course of actions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec

Comment: @Semanino's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50233450/355230) to the linked question sounds like the correct one to me.

Comment: It sounds right to me as well, thanks a lot for your suggestion!
What I can not understand is why the following code does not work:
Py_SetPath(L"C:\\Python\\Python3100_x86");
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();